# Script to get local user information in Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I want a script that will show all local users of a windows server (2003/2008) with all details like loginname, fullname, group etc etc. like "net user" gives all logins and then I need to do "net user login" to get info about a login. I want all informations in a single command / script. Please help

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like [plz email me teh codez](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez.aspx), which is kind of frowned upon. Also `"etc, etc"` isn't really a good way to enumerate your requirements. There are *a lot* of possible attributes that can be returned for a user. Please list all of the ones that you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner in Powershell:

```
([ADSI]"WinNT://localhost,computer" ).psbase.Children | ?{ $_.psbase.schemaclassname -eq 'user' } | Format-List *
```

Comment: This is two times in two days that you've beat me to a PS answer :)

Comment: To be fair, I googled it and streamlined the best scripts that I found